# if statement unix shell script

Tags: unix, if-statement

I am using if statement to check for a condition and assign values. A mail will be sent after that. I executing the script ( bash ) but nothing really happens and I have to exit; could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
if [ $var -eq 0 ]
then
subject="there are zero issues"
else
subject="there are issues"
fi

mail -s "$subject" abc@gmail.com
```

Comment: Can you do an `echo $subject` after the `fi` but before the call to `mail`?  What do you see?

Comment: so somehow the mail portion is not working

Comment: You're sending spam to an inappropriate email address?

Comment: i did not specify the message body  - thats why it was not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Unix `mail` command is waiting to receive a message body to send, but you have not provided one in your script.  Try this:

```
$ mail -s "$subject" abc@gmail.com < /home/user/yourmessage.txt
```

where `/home/user/yourmessage.txt` contains some message you wish to include in the email.

Comment: One more thing - I am getting nothing in the subject line - when I echo $subject i do get a result , so not sure why it is not appearing in the email subject

Comment: Maybe you need to use `mailx` instead of `mail`?  At the least, check your `mail` program to be sure it supports `-s "subject"` notation.  (Mac OS X has both `mail` and `mailx`, but both support `-s "subject'`.)  There aren't many other reasons why it would go wrong, unless you've done something very peculiar?

Comment: I agree with Jonathan.  The syntax you have for including a subject is correct, unless of course your flavor of Linux doesn't support it.

Comment: ok thanks guys - i will try to solve the subject issue - sending the mail was what I really needed!! thanks!!